# How do I get the current user connected account so that I use it when making stripe api calls for different connected accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-connect

```
 def stripe_charges_not_paid
    if Rails.env.production?
      Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_PRO']
    else
      Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    end
    Stripe::Charge.list(limit: 100, paid: false ,stripe_account: CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)
  end
```

Right now its giving me an error uninitialized constant User::CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID on my terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the user's Stripe account the returned data includes `id` (it will start with "acct_...").  You should store the id in a field in the user record... what you call it is up to you but `:stripe_account_id` is a good choice.  Also, ensure that at time of account creation you set the account email to be the current_user email.

You can get a list of connected accounts with the following in your User model...

```
  require "stripe"
  def stripe_user_account
    return @stripe_user_account if defined? @stripe_user_account
    if Rails.env.production?
      Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_PRO']
    else
      Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    end

    Stripe::Account.list(limit: 99).each do |account|
      if account.email == self.email
        @stripe_user_account = account.id 
        break
      end
    end
    @stripe_user_account
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but my problem is not getting the customer id,it is getting the connected stripe account id which starts with acct_****** to change depending on the current user.

Comment: My stripe_charges_not_paid method is in the User model